# Gluon sample application failing on ios devices

Tags: gluon-mobile, robovm

I am trying to run my gluon sample application on ios device but I am getting an exception while launching the app using the command `./gradlew --info launchIosDevice`.
The error stack trace is

```
        org.robovm.libimobiledevice.LibIMobileDeviceException: IDEVICE_E_NOT_ENOUGH_DATA
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.IDevice.checkResult(IDevice.java:197)
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.IDeviceConnection.receive(IDeviceConnection.java:109)
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.receiveGdbAck(AppLauncher.java:475)
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.sendReceivePacket(AppLauncher.java:485)
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.pipeStdOut(AppLauncher.java:763)
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launchInternal(AppLauncher.java:734)
        at org.robovm.libimobiledevice.util.AppLauncher.launch(AppLauncher.java:1052)
        at org.robovm.compiler.target.ios.AppLauncherProcess$1.run(AppLauncherProcess.java:67)
```

Although the app is installed on device but it crashes while starting.
I am using mac-os version 10.14.6 and iPhone 8+ with software version 13.3
Xcode version is 11.3

Comment: There seem to be an issue with RoboVM and JavaFX since iOS 13.2.3. (At least that’s the version I noticed the issue for the first time), which is not clearly yet what has changed in iOS and made apps crashing and not being able to debug through terminal

Comment: It seams to be an robovm issue. I've found this: https://github.com/MobiVM/robovm/issues/414

Comment: Check the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/a/60017012/3635345

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a problem with the latest version of Gluon ( 5.0.2 charm) not playing nicely with iOS 13.2.3 and beyond. Prior to this it worked fine.

Comment: No, it does not have to do with that error you are referring. That has been fixed with 2.3.10-SNAPSHOT of RoboVM