# How to change version of RoboVM compiler to 2.3.10-SNAPSHOT in Gluon Mobile

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I have an issue with running my JavaFX/Gluon Mobile App on iPadOS 13.3 Actually the similar issue is described here: [Gluon sample application failing on ios devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59386529/gluon-sample-application-failing-on-ios-devices) I've identify that the problem is caused by RoboVM and should be fixed in the version 2.3.10-SNAPSHOT

How can I change the version of RoboVM used by Gluon? In the Gluon documentation is mentioned the ios gradle extension property ***robovmVersion***. This property can be set to the version robovmVersion ='2.3.5-ios12' but not 2.3.10. The reason is that on the [bintray](https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/gluonhq/robovm-dist/) there is no version 2.3.10.

Is there any way to force Gluon Mobile to use RoboVM 2.3.10?

Comment: You can try to modify and build locally the jfxmobile plugin, by changing the [2.3.5-ios12](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/db6e767a8d428af8dfaf8b9096aad5b4dc3b2d91/build.gradle?at=default#build.gradle-26) dependency. Based on the [`robovmVersion`](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin/src/db6e767a8d428af8dfaf8b9096aad5b4dc3b2d91/src/main/groovy/org/javafxports/jfxmobile/plugin/ios/IosExtension.groovy?at=default#lines-20), you will have to change the dependencies in JFXMobilePlugin.

Comment: I have been playing with that the last days. You can download a sample from https://bitbucket.org/javasuns/files/downloads/JavaFXRoboVM.tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a temporary solution until the JavaFXPorts repository gets updated. There seems to be an issue with **iOS 13.3** and **JavaFX native libraries** that's why apps crash even when using the latest **2.3.10-SNAPSHOT**.

The breaking line of code was identified yesterday by *Demyan Kimitsa* who suggested to remove assert from the following native class

**GlassApplication.m:635**

```
assert(pthread_key_create(&GlassThreadDataKey, NULL) == 0);
```

becomes

```
thread_key_create(&GlassThreadDataKey, NULL) == 0;
```

I have created a build with the above change in native libraries and with the use of **RoboVM 2.3.10-SNAPSHOT** everything runs normal again even in the latest iOS.

Now that the issue is identified, I believe it is a matter of time until a new JavaFXPorts fix is published.

If you can't wait, you can download the HelloWorld sample with the new binaries from [here](https://bitbucket.org/javasuns/files/downloads/JavaFXPorts.tar.gz). Adjust the parameters in build.gradle and you are ready to go.

Comment: Great finding! For complete reference, the `GlassApplication.m` file is located at the [JavaFXPorts repository](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/8u-dev-rt/src/tip/modules/graphics/src/main/native-glass/ios/GlassApplication.m#lines-635). And if you remove the `assert`, you can also remove `== 0`.

Comment: @JoséPereda probably you should check other places of assets to be sure that no initializations happen inside as I didn't check entire sources. Also it would be nice to store result of pthread_key_create invocation to local var and keep assert around this var.